# Flutter can't type UTF-8 values in TextFields

Tags: flutter, dart

I cannot type UTF-8 values to TextFields in Flutter. Is there anyway to make inputs utf-8 compatible ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
i think the problem was emulator doesn't support utf-8.
When i launched on my phone it works fine.